# Phonegap local storage returns empty result

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, web-sql

On app's first load, I retrieve data from storage (Phonegap's WebSQL storage type). Phonegap storage results load fine. Until...

When I go to another page in the app:
   `<a href="page2.html" rel="external">Link</a>`

If I return back to that main page from the second page using `window.location.href` in Javascript, I retrieve the WebSQL data again (same function as before).

Phonegap Storage calls the success function (no error), but with an *empty result set*. It seems to be loading from a second database where I haven't stored anything into (see edit below).

If I force quit app and reopen, storage loads fine again, which shows me that the results in the DB are NOT being deleted.

I load the storage after `ondeviceready` is fired. What could be wrong?

**Note:**
1. This is not happening on simulators. only happening on real *Android* 4.0 device.
2. This app uses jQuery / jQuery Mobile.

```
function ondeviceready() {
   db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "test DB", 2000000);
   // . . . //
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name', [], querysuccess, function(tx, e) {
         errorAlert();
      });
   }), errorCB;
}
```

**EDIT**:
I'm noticing now that if I add a new row when app is first loaded, it stores in one database. Then, if I go to the second page and then back to the first page, and I add another row, it also stores, but **in a separate database!** (so that's what it seems to be doing). So strange, I see this happening. All my rows are saved and persistent, but the query returns a different group of results depending on whether I went to the second page or not...

**Also:**
The second page is having a jQuery error for some reason. I just created a blank page with a script link to jQuery, and there is an error. Strange... I wonder if this error is affecting the database? I'm trying to discover how to solve this error.

Comment: Are you inserting any records in the table?

Comment: @VickyGonsalves yes, at first load I insert records. However, I didn't add any new records after leaving and coming _back_ to the first page. Which is why it returned no results after coming back to first page - because it's like it's creating a second database. See edit.

Comment: @KyawTun yes it works on iOS simulator

Comment: Could you do a quick test with my library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home i don't see problem reported with my library. the different is I use versionless opening.

Comment: @KyawTun I already have tried WebSQL without setting version and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered an issue similar to this one before, but my problem was that I was trying to write to the same database from the Java side and the Javascript side. This is how I was able to solve it:

- First I ran the app on an Android Simulator and used DDMS to access the databases and that is when I realised that the two were writing in different databases.
- I changed from using `WebSQL`, to using proper `SQLite` database, and I started getting consistent results after that. It's a drop-in replacement for the phonegap's implementation of database storage, so no need to change your code much. Please see https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-Android.

I think it's also important to note that `WebSQL` has some storage limitations, so you might be better off using `SQLite` that `WebSQL`. Please see: http://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/standards/2011/the-limitations-of-websql-and-offline-apps/

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Good information and good links. For now I'll stick with WebSQL using my solution, but maybe I'll switch in the future :)

Comment: I was having more database issues, so I just switched to pgsqlite and so far so good, thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Good choice, you can't go wrong with sqlite. I'm glad you have your problem sorted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is I now load the external HTML page through Ajax:

`$.mobile.changePage("page2.html");`

I also switched to pgsqlite as recommended.